# How to control multiple activities in Android Studio

Tags: android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I am currently working on a Formula app that has every formula of Physics, Chemistry and Maths.
But the problem is that each subject has atleast 20 chapters, so that's like 60-70 chapters. So if I will make that much activities my app size will definitely increase. And also my code will be complicated. Is there any easy way to do this. Maybe fragments or something like that ?

```
String phyChapters[] = {"Kinematics", "Laws of Motion", "Work Power Energy", "Rotational Motion",
        "Gravitation", "Thermodynamics", "Kinetic Theory of Gases", "Properties of Matters",
        "Oscillations", "Waves and Sound", "Current & Electricity", "Heating Eff. of Current",
        "Magnetic Eff. of Current", "Magnetism", "Electromagnetic Induction", "Alternating Current",
        "Electromagnetic Waves", "Ray Optics", "Wave Optics", "Dual Nature of Matter", "Atomic Physics",
        "Nuclear Physics", "Electronics"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_physics);

    ListAdapter phyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_config, R.id.textView, phyChapters);
    ListView phyList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.phyListView);
    phyList.setAdapter(phyAdapter);
```

Can I get the source code ?

Comment: It's _too broad_ to answer your question. Because, "Can I get the source code?" StackOverflow isn't code writing service. But I suggest you to use Fragments in your app. For example, create ChemistryActivity and create/host 20 Fragments (or as per your requirement) under that Activity. This is based only on my opinion.

Comment: If I use fragments, will it change the layout of whole ChemistryActivity (Temporarily)

Comment: ChemistryActivity remains same but when you switch between Fragments under ChemistryActivity the layout changes. But you have to create different layouts for each Fragments (if visualizations different for each screen). For more refer [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments)